# Fasthosts and Heroku

Tags: email, heroku

I have an app on Heroku, for which I have pointed a Cname record to both the www and naked domain.

However this is creating a problem when people try to reply to our emails from that domain. They are being routed through Heroku somehow - it is only on reply though:

```
Delivery has failed to these recipients or groups:

paul@us-east-1-a.route.herokuapp.com
The server has tried to deliver this message, without success, and has stopped trying.         

The following organization rejected your message: us-east-1-a.route.herokuapp.com.

Diagnostic information for administrators:

Generating server: sofia.vsl-net.com

paul@us-east-1-a.route.herokuapp.com
us-east-1-a.route.herokuapp.com #<us-east-1-a.route.herokuapp.com #4.4.7> #SMTP#
```

In the case above, they were replying to an email sent from paul@mydomain.com.

Fasthosts as usual are no help at all, can anyone shed some light on this?

Thanks

ETA - It only seems to be some people that are having problems replying to us. I can send/receive from another imap account, and also a gmail account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CNAME records cannot coexist with MX records. Your MX records will be ignored and the domain will get the MX records of the CNAME's **destination** (likely something like proxy.heroku.com here).

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11693394/using-email-w-heroku-and-cname
- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/zerigo_dns#managing-mx-and-other-host-records

Comment: Thanks for answering. So how can you use email on the same domain that you have a Heroku app? Surely you've got to have a CNAME record in their somewhere as Heroku will not let you have an IP address to add A records?

Comment: Scratch the above - I think i've fixed it. I removed the CNAME record for the naked domain, which as you say can't work, and instead added an A record, and used the http://wwwizer.com/naked-domain-redirect service to do a 301 redirect. Just waiting for things to propagate to see if it's actually worked...